# copying a symlink to a target file using cp -t

Tags: file-copy, file-management, readlink

I have a symlink to a file on my Ubuntu system, and I need to copy the original file to a different directory and have a new name there. I am able to copy it to a different directory using

```
readlink -ne my_symlink | xargs -0 cp -t /tmp/
```

But I am not able to give a new name in the destination directory.
Basically, I am looking for a command that could look like:

```
readlink -ne base.txt | xargs -0 cp -t /tmp/newnametofile
```

When I try the exact same command above, it gives me `file or directory not found` error.

Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: for me `cp` follows symlinks in SOURCE, you can try `-L` option if it is not the case for you.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked.. I had been trying '-l' .. Simple cp with '-L' Did the job..

Comment: @pLumo you may as well post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cp` will dereference symlinks with `-L` option.

This should work:

```
cp -L my_symlink /tmp/newnametofile
```

---

Regarding your `xargs`, `-t`, `--target-directory` option of `cp` only takes DIRECTORY as input. You could make it work using `xargs -I{} cp {} /tmp/newnametofile` (but I'd use `cp -L` anyways...

Comment: Great! I managed to copy a directory full of symlinks with `cp -r -L`